# what is the differences between "write metadata" and "set metadata" in ovs?

Tags: openvswitch

I mean, write metadata is implemented by the instructions in openflow, on the other side, set field in action can also set the metadata ,what is the differences between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, [`WRITE_METADATA`](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/c7e22c6e4e94863ac933090a7b0cc3bc2cb06b40/ofproto/ofproto-dpif-xlate.c#L6714-L6718) and [`SET_FIELD` for metadata](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/c7e22c6e4e94863ac933090a7b0cc3bc2cb06b40/ofproto/ofproto-dpif-xlate.c#L6585-L6601) do the same in Open vSwitch.

I'm guessing both are exposed by Open vSwitch to follow the OpenFlow specifications as much as possible. OpenFlow has a clear distinction between Actions and Instructions (cf. Sections 5.5 and 5.6 of [OpenFlow v1.5.1](https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-switch-v1.5.1.pdf)): Instructions are attached to rules and applied at the end of each table, whereas Actions are attached to packets (using the `Write-Actions` Instruction) and applied at the end of the pipeline (or before if the `Apply-Actions` Instruction is executed). In Open vSwitch, the distinction is not as clear: Actions can be attached to both packets and rules.

Thus, while `WRITE_METADATA` is different from `SET_FIELD` in the OpenFlow specification because the first is an Instruction, the second an Action, you can do the same as `WRITE_METADATA` with a `SET_FIELD` Action.